# setTaskDescription does not change the icon

Tags: android, android-activity, android-icons

Trying to call the `setTaskDescription` method but it does not change in the icon in the recents screen. The icon is still the default app's icon. So this call seems to have no effect at all.

```kotlin
val taskDescription = TaskDescription.Builder()
    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon2)
    .build()
setTaskDescription(taskDescription)
```

Why does this have no effect? How can I change the icon in the recents screen from code? (without changing the actual activity icon)

Tested on both Android 12 and Android 14

Comment: `android.R.color.holo_blue_bright` - this is a **colour** resource, not a drawable. Are you sure that's intended?

Comment: @Edric yes, I also tried with a Bitmap drawable resource and no effect